# How to say "*" and "#"?

Tags: american-english

When I make a phone call, I'm not sure how to say the snow-like symbol and "#" correctly on the keyboard of phone in English, or I have no idea what people are talking about when they say a word which may seem to referring to "#" or the snow-like symbol. Could you please tell me how to say them? Thank you.

Comment: "Asterisk" and "octothorpe".  Or, if you prefer, "star" and "pound sign".

Comment: @Hot Licks: in Britain we call it hash not pound sign because of our currency sign.

Comment: @ChrisM - Telephone prompts in the US will tell you "Please enter your number, followed by the pound sign."

Comment: @Hot Licks That's fascinating! Thank you for sharing that. Over here £ is the pound sign, of course. I wonder why # would be called a pound sign.

Comment: @Hot Licks we call this # hashtag.

Comment: @ChrisM - I think it's called a "pound sign" because it was, in the past, used as an abbreviation for avoirdupois pounds in bookkeeping and on shop price labels and the like.

Comment: The [ASCII computer code standard](http://www.ascii-code.com/) (which dates to 1963) refers to "#" as "number sign" and "*" as "asterisk".

Answer (score 2):

Usually they are called the "star" key for "*" and the "pound" key for "#", although "hashtag" seems to be growing in use as the name for the "#" key lately.

Answer (score 1):

The key labeled ✻ was officially named the star key. The original design used a symbol with six points, but an asterisk (*) with five points commonly appears in printing.[citation needed] "#" is officially called the number sign key, but other names such as pound key, hash key, hex key, octothorpe, gate, and square, are common, depending national or personal preference.

Comment: "Officially" by whom?

Answer (score 1):

"Star" and "hash", respectively.

For example: *10# would be pronounced "Star - Ten - Hash", or "Star - One - Zero - Hash"

Answer (score 0):

asterisk for '*' and sharp or pound for '#'

Comment: That is *not* what the symbols are customarily called in reference to the telephone keypad.

Comment: But we do used it. I guess in your country don't use it as we used it.