# What symbol is called 'hash' in US English?

Tags: symbols

In the UK the word hash refers to this symbol: #

What symbol does 'hash' refer to in US English?

And what word is used to describe the '£' symbol?

```
      US     British
#     pound  hash
£     ?      pound
?     hash
```

Comment: Why do you think Americans call ***any*** symbol "hash"? 

Comment: The # is also known as a *hash* in the U.S., but whether it is called a *hash sign*, *pound sign*, *number sign*, *crosshatch*, *octatherp*, and so on depends on how it is used. £ is rarely encountered outside of financial publications and there is rarely a need to refer to the symbol as opposed to what it represents, but it might be read aloud as *pounds*, *British pounds*, *pounds sterling*, and so on depending on context.

Comment: @choster I’m with Peter: I’ve never heard any symbol called a *hash* in the US; the # symbol is universally the number sign or the pound sign.

Comment: @tchrist I work in software and, perhaps because of the South Asian presence in the office, we do say *hash* or *hash mark* for this symbol, as in *you can comment out those lines by putting a hash in front of them*. This is similar to the use of *bang* for *exclamation point* or *pipe* for *vertical bar*.

Comment: @choster Yeah scripting languages you comment out with # by "pounding out" here, but we've always said pound-define and pound-include for `#define` and `#include` under C or C++, least 'round these parts.

Comment: Etymology tells us that  lb   written by hand gradually turned into  # .  Perhaps even in Britain, in the Olden Days before they switched to kg.

Comment: @tchrist Really? I didn’t know Americans called it that. I was trained in Australia, and we’ve always pronounced #define and #include and hash-define and hash-include.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, really. I swear it's true.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27333, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117219, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161720, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255912, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/376462, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438092

Answer (score 8):

[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign)

> The symbol # is most commonly known as the number sign,`[1]` hash,`[2]` or pound sign.`[3]`

If I give my address as: `436 Main Street # 201`, that is read "number".

If I add to my Facebook post `#MeToo`, that is a "hash tag"

If I write `5# of potatoes`, I read it "5 pounds".

All of these are used in the US.

For `£`, I would probably say "Pounds Sterling" or "British Pounds" or something.

**added**
Request in a comment for reference on # for pounds ...
It seems to have been used only in America.  Nowadays it is mostly gone, except occasionally for hand-written signs.

Lots of historical examples are found [HERE](http://widespacer.blogspot.com/2015/10/the-sign-of-number.html)

For example, this one dates from 1850.
[image]
At the top, 7-1/4 pounds of nails; at the bottom, 6 pounds of nails.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the main context where the **#** is called a *pound sign* is on telephone keypads, where there's no chance of confusion with British currency. (And it's also sometimes called a tic-tac-toe board.)

Comment: @1006a You see # to mean *pound* used on hand-written signs at roadside produce stands. Programmers always call it *pound* but for telephones it’s just *number*. I’ve never heard anybody call it *hash* who wasn’t some young eurotwitter junkie. It’s almost like that’s an import, not native.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, that's mostly my experience, too, except that I now hear *hash **tag*** quite a lot. On the subject of "pound", I meant to distinguish when you would read the symbol as saying *pound* (as in "$1 for 5#" or similar) and when you would actually talk about the symbol-as-symbol and call it a *pound sign* (mostly in contexts like "enter your sixteen-digit personal code followed by the pound sign"). That phrase seems a little more ambiguous to me outside the context of automated phone trees, but totally unambiguous within that context.

Comment: In business, on orders for products and suchlike the pound sign refers to a number. It stands then for the word number.

Comment: Can you give a reference for '5# of potatoes'? I've never seen it used like that.

Answer (score 0):

@choster I live in the US and I've seen the # called a hashtag both on Twitter and Facebook. As for the £ symbol, which is not included in the American computer keyboard, I heard of it as a pound sign on in finance language teaching books.

Comment: The number sign #  is most definitely not a hashtag, the twitter messaging address.

Comment: Please do not leave a comment as an answer.